# Set multidimensional array in Yii::app()->request->post

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array, yii

I am trying to set multi-dimensional array in Yii post:

```
Yii::app()->request->post(['PaymentMethodForm'][$_POST['PaymentOptionsForm']['payment_option']]['jazzcash_phone'], $phoneNumber);
```

to replace traditional $_POST.

```
$_POST['PaymentMethodForm'][$_POST['PaymentOptionsForm']['payment_option']]['jazzcash_phone'] = $phoneNumber;
```

$_POST code works fine but Yii post doesn't.

I have to replace all $_POST with Yii post.

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::app()->request->post()` is GETTING value, with default fallback. It is not setting anything. If You need to populate $_POST array, You should use it directly. More info about request: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html

Your line Would evaluate to:

```
$name = $request->post('name', '');
// equivalent to: $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

However, because You are not assigning value to any variable, it does nothing.

Comment: Is there any Yii syntax to set post array instead of $_POST?

Comment: I don't think so. What is wrong with using $_POST array?